# Why my test accuracy falls when i use more epochs for training my CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a problem with my CNN. I trained my model for 50 epochs (BN, Dropouts used) and i got test accuracy 92%. After that i trained my  exact same network again but for 100 epochs, with just the same tuning and generalization techniques, and my test set's accuracy fell to 79%. Due to my small data set i used data augmentation (horizontal and vertical flip). I cannot explain this, can somebody help?

```
import numpy as np 
import tensorflow as tf
from numpy.random import seed
seed(1)

tf.compat.v1.set_random_seed(2)
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True)
session = tf.InteractiveSession(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
import os
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND']='tensorflow'


import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback, ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD,Adam
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
import matplotlib as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import itertools

keras.initializers.glorot_normal(seed=42)

train_path='C:/Users/Panagiotis Gkanos/Desktop/dataset/40X/train'
train_batches=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,horizontal_flip=True,
vertical_flip=True).flow_from_direct ory(train_path,
                                                  target_size=[400,400],
                                                  classes=['malignant','benign'],
                                                  class_mode='categorical',batch_size=40)

valid_path='C:/Users/Panagiotis Gkanos/Desktop/dataset/40X/valid'
valid_batches=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255).flow_from_directory(valid_path,
                                                  target_size=[400,400],
                                                  classes=['malignant','benign'],
                                                  class_mode='categorical',batch_size=20)

test_path='C:/Users/Panagiotis Gkanos/Desktop/dataset/40X/test'
test_batches=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255).flow_from_directory(test_path,
                                                  target_size=[400,400],
                                                  classes=['malignant','benign'],
                                                  class_mode='categorical',batch_size=20)


model=Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(16,(3,3),strides=2,padding='same',input_shape=(400,400,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(16,(3,3),strides=1,padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(16,(3,3),strides=1,padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),strides=2))



model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),strides=1,padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),strides=1,padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),strides=1,padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),strides=2))



model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),strides=2))



model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),strides=2))



model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

#learn_control = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_acc', patience=5,
                             # verbose=1,factor=0.2, min_lr=1e-7)

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
history=model.fit_generator(train_batches,steps_per_epoch=20 ,validation_data=valid_batches,
                        validation_steps=8 ,epochs=100)
#,callbacks=[learn_control])

model.evaluate(test_batches)

def plot_loss(history):
    train_loss=history.history['loss']
    val_loss=history.history['val_loss']
    x=list(range(1,len(val_loss)+1))
    plt.plot(x,val_loss,color='red',label='validation loss')
    plt.plot(x,train_loss,label='training loss')
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.ylabel('Loss')
    plt.title('Loss vs. Epoch')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

def plot_accuracy(history):
    train_acc=history.history['acc']
    val_acc=history.history['val_acc']
    x=list(range(1,len(val_acc)+1))
    plt.plot(x,val_acc,color='red',label='validation acc')
    plt.plot(x,train_acc,label='training acc')
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
    plt.title('Accuracy vs. Epoch')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

plot_loss(history)

plot_accuracy(history)
```

Comment: what do the plots show?

Comment: Is this a programming question, or a stats/ML one? You can find a discussion of relevant Stack Exchange sites [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms). Also, see: [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

This is what is referred to as "overfitting." If your network had better test performance at 50 epochs, you may want to stop there.

In this case it is likely due to having a small data set for which the network will be unable to find general patterns which fit all cases. Instead it is fitting to small recurring details from your training data.

For instance, if you were to train a CNN to perform animal classification, bird or dog, using only blue birds in your training set and dogs of various colors in your training set. If you test your network with a picture of a bird that is any color other than blue, it is likely that it will classify as a dog because your network learned that everything blue is a bird and everything else is a dog instead of learning what features are unique to birds and what features are unique to dogs.

The short of it is, you likely just need a bigger, more varied data set. You could also implement early stopping, which will stop the network from training before it overfits to the data. Otherwise you can try other forms of regularization, but this is a difficult problem to overcome.

Comment: Yeah i thought so, i will use further data augmentation as a first step. Thank for your help appreciate it.

Comment: Also, with dropout, you can the LeakyReLU activation via `tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU`